# Memory Leak within nested while loop even though I free after both loops

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind is telling me my memory is leaking where "result" is allocated in two different locations. I free result in my code. I'm really stuck. Interestingly, commenting out the second free doesn't worsen my memory leak, meaning it's not actually doing anything. Thoughts?

```
void index_build(const char *pathname, index_t *index) 
{
    char *filename = count_malloc(strlen(pathname) + 5);
    int id = 1;
    sprintf(filename, "%s/%d", pathname, id);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    while (fp != NULL) {
        char *url = count_malloc(200);
        fgets(url, 50000, fp);
        char *depth = count_malloc(sizeof(fgets(depth, 5000000, fp)) + 1);
        fgets(depth, 500000, fp);
        int d = atoi(depth);
        webpage_t *page = pageDir_load(url, d);
        int pos = 0;
        char *result = count_malloc(sizeof(webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos)) + 1);
        result = webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos);
        while (result != NULL) {
            if (index_find(index, result) == NULL) {
                counters_t *new = counters_new();
                counters_add(new, id);
                index_insert(index, result, new);
            }
            else {
                counters_t *current = index_find(index, result);
                counters_add(current, id);
            }
            free(result);
            result = count_malloc(sizeof(webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos)) + 1);
            result = webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos);
        }
        free(result);
        id++;
        fclose(fp);
        sprintf(filename, "%s/%d", pathname, id);
        fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        free(depth);
        webpage_delete(page);
    }
    free(filename);
}
```

valgrind error:

```
54 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==3516925==    at 0x483980B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==3516925==    by 0x40227D: count_malloc (memory.c:54)
==3516925==    by 0x401572: index_build (indexer.c:63)
==3516925==    by 0x40146C: main (indexer.c:46)
==3516925== 
==3516925== 495 bytes in 55 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==3516925==    at 0x483980B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==3516925==    by 0x40227D: count_malloc (memory.c:54)
==3516925==    by 0x40161B: index_build (indexer.c:76)
==3516925==    by 0x40146C: main (indexer.c:46)
```

Comment: malloc doesn't initialize the variable, just allocates the memory right? @user3121023

Comment: `while (fp != NULL) {}` strange loop. Not forbidden, but just strange. You could use two functions: one to cycle the files, and one to process a single file.

Comment: @wildplasser don't think that's what's causing the leaks tho.

Comment: `sizeof(fgets(...))` doesn’t seem sensible. I think you need to rethink what you are doing here. Many weird things happening. But the leak is most likely what user3121023 mentioned.

Comment: @user3121023 sorry, why does the assignment lose track of the memory? How can I fix it?

Comment: @user3121023 ah, does that mean I don't need to malloc at all?

Comment: @decheftw It is not causing the leaks. It is causing complexity, which is the cause of your confusion IMHO.

Comment: @decheftw For instance: your outer loop is basically a loop on `id++;` Why is it not a `for(id=1; ...; id++) {...}` loop ?

Comment: You allocate 5Mbytes for `depth`, read only _up-to_ 500Kbytes, and then only use it as input to `atoi()` which will convert at most 10 digits and a sign.  That makes little sense.  and `url` (the one you fail to free) hardly needs to be dynamically allocated in any case.  Worse you allocate 200 bytes, then read up to 5Kbytes into it which is just nonsense - the failure to free 200 bytes is the least of your problems with this code.  The use of "magic numbers" is just one issue.

Comment: @Clifford I fixed my memory leaks. You're right, I never free'd URL, but for some reason it's not throwing anything in valgrind. I think because I use URL in webpage and then call webpage delete. Thanks for the advice on mallocing sizes.

Comment: Valdrind is indicating the precise line number in indexer,c that is at fault - perhaps you could indicate in your fragment which lines those are?

Comment: @Clifford that doesn't matter, I've already fixed the memory leak.

Comment: @decheftw It does if this question is going to get an answer.  If you have solved the problem you can post an answer to your own question.  If that is not to be done the question serves no purpose on SO and should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grep'd your code for all malloc's and frees like this:

```
egrep "malloc|free"
```

I got these results:

```
char *filename = count_malloc(strlen(pathname) + 5);
    char *url = count_malloc(200);
    char *depth = count_malloc(sizeof(fgets(depth, 5000000, fp)) + 1);
    char *result = count_malloc(sizeof(webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos)) + 1);
        free(result);
        result = count_malloc(sizeof(webpage_getNextWord(page, &pos)) + 1);
    free(result);
    free(depth);
free(filename);
```

Above, I see that `url` is never free'd.